# Sorting distinct values order by count using Lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I am trying to select the distinct Main Categories in descending order by count. But getting the following error:

> DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
>
> Parameter name: input

Here is my code:

```
var Categories = products.Where(p => p.IsActive == true)
    .Select(n => n.MainCategory).Distinct().ToArray().OrderByDescending(p => p.Count());
if (Categories != null)
{
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var Category in Categories)
    {
        j++;
        var brands = products.Where(p => p.IsActive == true && p.MainCategory == Category && p.Brand != string.Empty && p.Brand != null).Select(n => n.Brand).Distinct().ToArray();
        if (brands == null || brands.Length == 0)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"/hi-fi/{1}\" class=\"list-group-item list-group-item-success colordiv\">{0}</a><a href=\"#demo{2}\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#MainMenu\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus\"></a>\n", Category, Category.Replace(" ", "-"), j);
        }
        else
        {
            //code to list brands}
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: You will need to use a `.GroupBy()` to group your products by `MainCategory`and then get the `.Count()` of each group

Comment: @StephenMuecke i can't use GroupBy(), because it affect other queries as well

Comment: What other queries? (you need to use `.GroupBy()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke for the query 'var brands = products.Where(p => p.IsActive == true && p.MainCategory == Category && p.Brand != string.Empty && p.Brand != null).Select(n => n.Brand).Distinct().ToArray()'. Here for 'p.MainCategory == Category', the error is "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String and 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string.Project1.Models.Product>''"

Comment: But that is a completely separate query and is not related to the query in your question. Your query should be `var categories = products.Where(p => p.IsActive == true).GroupBy(x => x.MainCategory).Select(y => new { Category = y.Key, Count = y.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke No sir, that query comes in foreach loop, here it is            'foreach (var Category in Categories)' and the error now is "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String and 'AnonymousType#1'"

Comment: What?? Why in the world do your have a linq query inside a `for` loop (that makes no sense)? And there is nothing at all in your question about a loop. What are you really wanting to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke First i'm trying to select the distinct Main Categories in descending order by count and then listing those categories in side-bar

Comment: And that is exactly what the query I gave above does

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes sir that is perfect, but in foreach loop, i have to use that categories to select the brands under that particular category which i earlier mentioned as 'error query'.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's ok sir, i'll figure it out.thanks a lot for ur time.. :-)

Comment: Having a linq query inside a `foreach` loop makes no sense. Edit your question to explain what your really trying to do so other users don't waste their time tying to add an answer to a bad/incomplete question.

Comment: No time now but will look at it in a few hours. Note `if (Categories != null)` is pointless since `Categories` can never be `null` (just an empty collection). And why in the world are you generating html in the controller instead of the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's not in controller, that's in the model

Comment: That's even worse!

Comment: Sorry, but none of this really makes much sense and is awful practice. I suggest you give an example of some rows of data, and what you expect the result to be. My best guess is you want to list the main categories, and under each main category, you want to list all product brands associated with that main category

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes sir, your guess is right

Comment: Then the query simply becomes `var categories = products.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.Brand != null).GroupBy(x => x.MainCategory).Select(y => new { Category = y.Key, Brands = y.Select(z => z.Brand).Distinct(), Count = y.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);` And then you project that into a view model and you generate the html in the view (**not** in model) using nested loops

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah..!! thank you sir, thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

You shoul read this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916(v=vs.110).aspx
I think below code will work for your need.

```
public class MainCategory
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Datas { get; set; }
}

public class SpecialComprarer : IComparer<MainCategory>
{
    public int Compare(MainCategory x, MainCategory y)
    {
        if (x.Datas.Count() == y.Datas.Count())
            return 0;
        else if (x.Datas.Count() > y.Datas.Count())
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

You can you aboves like below

```
List<MainCategory> db = new List<MainCategory> {

        new MainCategory { Datas = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" } },
        new MainCategory { Datas = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" } },
        new MainCategory { Datas = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" } },
        new MainCategory { Datas = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" } }
         };
        List<MainCategory> x = db.OrderByDescending(m => m, new SpecialComprarer()).ToList();
```